# "Add to Cart" not working after moved local server to live server in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.2

`Add to cart` functionality not working after moved files and database from local computer server to live server.

Same files and database is works fine for local computer.

After moved files and database, I have done these:

- Changed paths/URL.
- Reindex.
- Setup upgrade
- Static content deploy.
- Cleared cache.

So, Any idea guys why i am having this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any error on consol or log file?

Comment: No issue i have found in consol and log file.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by cleared browser cache and cookie. Thanks for your advice. @DhirenVasoya